# Can't connect wpdatatables to ms sql database

Tags: sql-server, database, wordpress

I want to connect the Wordpress pluggin wpdatatables to my Ms sql database, but every time i try it appear the next message:

"wpDataTables could not connect to mssql server. mssql said: There was a problem with your SQL connection - could not find driver"

Comment: Is it possible you typed `mssql` into the Host field? This needs to be the IP address or fully-qualified domain name of your Microsoft SQL Server instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I put the server name in the Host field, but Im not sure if this is correct.